# Constructor Initializer List vs Constructor Body

Tags: c++, constructor

Let's say **someString** initialization is a tad complicated, hence we write a simple member function **stringInitialization()** with which to initialize **someString** in the body of the constructor:

```
class DemoL {
private:

    int someNumber;
    std::string someString;

    void stringInitialization() {
        if (someNumber == 1) {
            someString = "FIRSTSTRING";
        } else if (someNumber == 2) {
            someString = "SECONDSTRING";
        } else {
            someString = "";
        }
    }

public:
    explicit DemoL(int rNumber) :
            someNumber(rNumber) {
        stringInitialization();
    }
};
```

This way, I'd assume, **someString** will be default initialized before the body of the constructor and only after that will it be modified by calling **stringInitialization()**.

So, let's modify the code a bit, so that we initialize **someString** in the constructor initializer list:

```
class DemoL {
private:

    int someNumber;
    std::string someString;

    std::string stringInitialization() const {
        if (someNumber == 1) {
            return "FIRSTSTRING";
        } else if (someNumber == 2) {
            return "SECONDSTRING";
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }

public:
    explicit DemoL(int rNumber) :
            someNumber(rNumber),
            someString(stringInitialization()) {}
};
```

Would you be so kind as to tell me whether the second variant is more efficient and correct?

Comment: You can see the performance difference between both cases in this live demo: https://quick-bench.com/q/2Tt_R0fZXJtAYp_rUIIz5ENdp8U. It shows that the assignment to the default-constructed string is much slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. The constructor `DemoL(int rNumber)` needs to be able to default construct the member `someString` and this is no problem because `std::string` is default constructible.

One obvious point is that one member could be not default-constructible, in which case you would *have to* initialize it.

But even if it is, default constructing it could be a waste of resources, if you are changing it right after, so the second alternative seems better to me as it goes straight to the point.

<s>However, since `stringInitialization` returns by value, I would use `std::move`</s>, no, this is actually a bad idea, as pointed out in the comments.

So as a conclusion:

- the two codes are the same as regards `someNumber`
- the first code default-initializes `someString` ("calls" `std::basic_string<...>::basic_string`) and then assigns it (calls `std::basic_string<...>::operator=`)
- the second code constructs the return `std::string` value from the sting literals when the call to `stringInitialization` returns (calls `basic_string<...>::basic_string(const char*)`), and then copy-constructs `someString` (calls `basic_string<...>::basic_string(basic_string&&)`); actually copy elision happens because `stringInitialization` returns an rvalue.

Comment: No, don't do this: `someString{std::move(stringInitialization())}`. It makes no sense (`stringInitialization()` is rvalue by itself) and it **makes things worse**. Namely, it hinders copy elision. Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/jPd8qPja4.

Comment: @DanielLangr, going back to my mistake, does that mean that using `std::move` would prevent copy elision and force move-construction, or not event that would be possible resulting in a copy-construction? As in, would the pessimization be as bad as possible or "half" of that?

Comment: A function call expression with a function that returns _by value_ has category _rvalue_. Which constructor will be generally called depends on which constructors are available. If both copy and move constructors are, move will be called (an rvalue may be bound both to const lvalue references as well as to rvalue references, but the latter will be preferred).

Comment: Also note, that copy elision is not guaranteed in all cases. It is guaranteed since C++17 only if an rvalue is returned; then it is called RVO. Before C++17 or when returning an lvalue, copy elision is not guaranteed. However, all sane modern compilers will perform it.